# Testing with Enzyme v3 - class added to a node in componentDidMount isn't found with wrapper.find()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

Running this...

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ref.classList.add('test');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={ el => { this.ref = el; }}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

describe('MyComponent', () => {

  it('should render', () => {

    let wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);

    // element with "test" class is visible in markup
    console.log(wrapper.html()); 

    // returns 0
    expect(wrapper.find('.test').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Results in this...

```
$ npm test

> enzyme-issue@1.0.0 test /Users/spenceravinger/GitHub/enzyme-issue
> jest

 FAIL  ./test.js
  MyComponent
    ✕ should render (28ms)

  ● MyComponent › should render

    expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      1
    Received:
      0

      at Object.<anonymous> (test.js:32:42)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

  console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
    Warning: React depends on requestAnimationFrame. Make sure that you load a polyfill in older browsers. 
    https://gist.github.com/gaearon/9a4d54653ae9c50af6c54b4e0e56b583

  console.log test.js:29
    <div><div class="test"></div></div>

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.017s
Ran all test suites.
```

I've open an issue on github: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1212

Here's some code: https://github.com/savinger/enzyme-issue

Comment: I've since added the requestAnimationFrame polyfill and babel-polyfill. Still fails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know either why it isn't working. The test will pass if you use the component state to set the `div`'s `className`. You could set up your component like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { divClass: '' };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ divClass: 'test' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={this.state.divClass}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// test
describe('MyComponent', () => {

  it('should render', () => {

    let wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);

    // element with "test" class is visible in markup
    console.log(wrapper.html());

    // returns 0
    expect(wrapper.find('.test').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Perhaps you'd like to use `classList` for a specific reason. In any case, I'm not sure why enzyme isn't finding your `.test` class with your current setup.